# Routerlink when clicked does not scroll up automatically?

Tags: html, angular

So, I have this code in my Angular project.

`<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/shop/category/Other">Others</a>`

Once clicked, it doesn't scroll at the top of the page unlike in using `href`. What should I do to make it scroll up automatically once the `a` tag has been clicked by the user?

Comment: Try a `window.scrollTo(0, 0)` in the `ngOnInit()` hook of the target component.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Didn't know it was just simple like that. @MichaelD